# Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect file format 'inter'

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I'm using an api that deals with MySQL. I was able to make queries so many times and I got the results properly. When I tried to run the same exact code and nothing changed on it I got this error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect file format 'inter'
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4006)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2468)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2629)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2719)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:1379)
    at WordNetSemanticSimilarity.PathApproach.MinPathLength.createWordnetTableInter(MinPathLength.java:80)
    at WordNetSemanticSimilarity.PathApproach.MinPathLength.<init>(MinPathLength.java:61)
    at WordNetSemanticSimilarity.TaxonomicApproach.TaxonomicMeasures.<init>(TaxonomicMeasures.java:52)
    at wnetss.WNetSS.main(WNetSS.java:41)
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
```

Something I'd like to mention is that my laptob was running the program and it has suddenly shutdown because of the battery, when I run the program again I got this error, not sure if this is the reason and how to fix it.

Comment: GG Oracle try to reinstall Java JRE

Comment: @RaymondNijland I'm not sure what  is the cause of the problem where exactly that file

Answer (score 1):

I think your table was Corrupt.
Check Status of your table by running command :-> "check table "Table Name";
and Repair your table using command:->" repair table table name;"

Comment: I think your table was Corrupt.
Check Status of your table by running command :-> "check table "Table Name";
and Repair your table using command:->" repair table table name;".

Or Try to Run one command on your MySql Command Prompt 
"REPAIR TABLE "TableName" USE_FRM;".           @PRAKASH SATHE(prakash.sathe1996@gmail.com)

Comment: Why not edit your answer to include the comment?